# Excel Assign a value (or multiple) if a column contains a specific word

Tags: excel

I have a long list of DOM Types which have a name. For example Other, After School Activities, Arts & Culture etc. Each of these column names have a corresponding value. For example Other is 30, Aboriginal Studies is 1. What I'm trying to do is in a new column assign the proper value to each of these columns. The catch is that some columns can have multiple names separated via ;#. How would I be able to accomplish this, separating the columns with multiple names with a comma. I want it to look like this

```
Name                                      Value
-----                                     -----
Music                                      36
Learning Resources                         32
After-School Activities;#Competitions      3,9
```

Comment: This is going to take Office 365 Excel for a formula answer.  If you have Office 365 then look under the tag TEXTJOIN and you will find many examples on how to do this.

Comment: I am using MS10

Comment: Then you will need vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your names are in `Column A` and your values are in `Column B`.
This will output the split names in `Column C` and your split values in `Column D.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Work_Sub()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim LR As Long, iName, iValue, iCell As Range
Dim j As Long, c As Long

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
c = 1

For Each iCell In ws.Range("A2:A" & LR)
    If InStr(iCell, ";#") Then
        iName = Split(iCell, ";#")
        iValue = Split(iCell.Offset(, 1), ",")
            If UBound(iName) = UBound(iValue) Then
                For j = LBound(iName) To UBound(iName)
                    ws.Range("C" & c) = iName(j)
                    ws.Range("D" & c) = iValue(j)
                    c = c + 1
                Next j
            Else
                ws.Range("C" & c) = "Unmatched splits"
            End If
        iName = ""
        iValue = ""
    Else
        iCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = iCell.Value
        iCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = iCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        c = c + 1
    End If
Next iCell

End Sub
```

*Not Tested. Probably over kill - just ran with the first method that came to mind*